# Is this data structure an adjacency list or hybrid of adjacency list & Tree

Tags: data-structures, binary-tree, adjacency-list

I just started a new job and I don't really understand their data structure... I was wondering if someone can help me with this
Our team said Binary Tree is too slow and moved to adjacency list. But... I don't think this is adjacency list... and I think this is slower than Binary Tree... 1 senior developer said I need to go back to school... I'm just too embarrassed to ask them...

I believe our tree structure is slower than Binary Search Tree when it performs search... Our team asked me to prove it by using mathematical equations and the actual time instead of avg/worst case...

Please check this image
[Data Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MVpmH.png)

Comment: how are you currently traversing the adjacency list?

Comment: To me, this data structure can only traverse from parent to child. If this is an adjacency list, we should have V and E

Comment: From your diagram it appears you can also move from child to parent (like in a graph) It's hard to answer which method is faster without knowing how the algorithms are implemented or anything about the data, if you include these details you may get a better answer

Comment: Ic. In the database. each node (row) contains ID, parent ID, and order. 

If insert && no siblings || insert && last order, insert into DB
else insert and reorder the remaining nodes by search the entire db with same parentID && order greater than inserted node.

Comment: if Delete && no sibling || delete && only node, delete from DB
else delete and reorder the remaining nodes by search the entire db with same parentID && order greater than deleted node

if search with parentID, search the entire db to match parentID
if search with currentID, search the entire db to match currentID
if search subset under parentID, search the entire db for n times.
etc.

I felt this algorithm is expensive.

Comment: Sorry is your data stored in a database table? Or by DB do you mean the structure? If it's stored in a table do you ever store the contents in memory and use it or do you just query and update the DB?

Comment: Yes it is stored in the database table. We just query and update the DB.
Sorry, i'm kinda new to this.

Comment: No worries, I'm confused though, databases and their tables have their own internal structure, their lookup, insert, and update speed will depend on your keys and your queries. Are there other reasons for why your data is structured this way? I'd recommend editing your original post with all this information, and possibly and code you have access to that may be useful